# Swift 4 Json Decoding, Which is the best/latest method, Using Codable or Decodable?

Tags: swift, swift4, decodable

In Swift 4.1 we can decode JSON like this:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: String
}

let people = [Person]()

func parseJSON(data: Data) {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStratergy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        self.people = try decoder.decode([Person].self, from: data)
    } catch let error {
        print(error as? Any)
    }
}
```

Q1. What is the difference if I use `Codable` instead of `Decodable`? Which is better?

Q2. How to use `decodeIfPresent` here?

Q3. How to decode if there is no `key` present in the JSON?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to encode and decode JSON in Swift4

Here is the JSON representation of a simple object User, let’s see how to deserialise those data into an object.

```
{
"id": 13,
"firstname" : "John",
"lastname" : "Doe",
"email" : "john.doe@lost.com"
}
```

Decoding JSON into object

I use a struct type to represent my object and include the protocol Decodable to allow deserialisation.

```
struct User : Decodable {
 let id : Int
 let firstname : String
 let lastname : String
 let email : String
}
```

Now we’re ready to decode it using JSONDecoder.

// assuming our data comes from server side

```
     let jsonString = "{ \"id\": 13, \"firstname\" : \"John\", \"lastname\" : \"Doe\", \"email\" : \"john.doe@lost.com\" }"



let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

    do {
       let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
       let user = try jsonDecoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)
      print("Hello \(user.firstname) \(user.lastname)")
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
```

Pretty easy right? Let’s see how to serialise it now.
Encoding object into JSON

First, we need update our struct to allow encoding. To do so, we just need to include protocol Encodable.

```
struct User : Encodable, Decodable {
 ...
}
```

Our object is ready to be serialised back to JSON. We follow the same process as before, using JSONEncoder this time. In that case, I’ll also convert the data into a String to be sure it’s working
// assuming we have an object to serialise

That’s still pretty easy! So what is Codable all about?
Well, Codable, is just alias of Encodable and Decodable protocols as you can see in it’s definition
public typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
If you don’t want your JSON keys to drive your naming, you can still customise them using CodingKeys. Described as an enum, it will automatically be picked up while encoding / decoding

```
    struct User : Codable {
     var id : Int
     var firstname : String
     var lastname : String
var email : String?

// keys
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "user_id"
    case firstname = "first_name"
    case lastname = "family_name"
    case email = "email_address"
}
```

}

To go further

https://medium.com/@phillfarrugia/encoding-and-decoding-json-with-swift-4-3832bf21c9a8

https://benoitpasquier.com/encoding-decoding-json-swift4/

Answer of Question 3: https://www.calhoun.io/how-to-determine-if-a-json-key-has-been-set-to-null-or-not-provided/

Answer (score 1):

Please if possible try to post separated questions, it is easier to answer and to read after.

---

For your first question: `Codable` is a protocol extending `Encodable` and `Decodable`.

**Decodable** is to parse from data to your models. For example from JSON data to structs.

**Encodable** is to make data from your models.

**Codable** contains both.